# Distinguish between multiple arguments and array argument in Java method

Tags: java, arguments

I have a method which accepts multiple arguments: `void doodle(Object o, Object... objects)`.

Is there any way to distinguish if `objects` is a real array or just one built from multiple arguments?

Overloading the method like `void doodle(Object o, Object[] objects)` is not allowed in Java.

Comment: No, there's no way. Why do you care?

Comment: Because I'm developing a tool for visualizing objects. Multiple arguments cause the argument objects to be rendered on the same level. Array objects would be grouped in the array.

Comment: Then you should not use varargs, because they're just syntactic sugar for passing an array.

Comment: Hmm, but I like the functionality of varargs to allow the user to visualize multiple objects at once... Hmm, may I should forget that...

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to distinguish, because there is no real difference.

`Object...` is nothing more than syntactic sugar, under the hood, the *real* method signature has `Object[]`, that's why you can't overload it, it's basically the same.

For your particular use case, you can test if the method has varargs and create the visualization accordingly, see if this helps:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#isVarArgs%28%29